# OpenVPN server issues

Tags: networking, arch-linux, openvpn, daemon

I am unable to connect to my OpenVPN server running on latest ArchLinux version, the port seems open if I scan from the outside, so im pretty sure its correctly forwarded, however the client displays "Connection Failed" message (tried using another client on another network, same response).

### server.conf

> port 465
>
> proto tcp
>
> dev tun
>
> ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
>
> cert /etc/openvpn/Caluka.crt
>
> key /etc/openvpn/Caluka.key
>
> dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem
>
> tls-auth /etc/openvpn/ta.key 0
>
> server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
>
> ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
>
> push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
>
> push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.254"
>
> push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
>
> comp-lzo
>
> user nobody
>
> group nobody
>
> persist-key
>
> persist-tun
>
> status openvpn-status.log
>
> log openvpn.log
>
> verb 9

### client.conf

> remote [DDNS] 465
>
> client
>
> dev tun
>
> proto tcp
>
> resolv-retry infinite
>
> nobind
>
> persist-key
>
> persist-tun
>
> ca "C:\OpenVPN\ca.crt"
>
> cert "C:\OpenVPN\Tirpitz.crt"
>
> key "C:\OpenVPN\Tirpitz.key"
>
> tls-auth "C:\OpenVPN\ta.key" 1
>
> ns-cert-type server
>
> comp-lzo
>
> verb 3

However, I get no output or log from the client other than "Connection Failed"

Server side output log set to maximum verbosity:

### openvpn.log

> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243092 Current Parameter Settings:
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243127   config = '/etc/openvpn/server.conf'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243133   mode = 1
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243137   persist_config = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243140   persist_mode = 1
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243143   show_ciphers = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243147   show_digests = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243150   show_engines = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243153   genkey = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243157   key_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243160   show_tls_ciphers = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243164 Connection profiles [default]:
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243167   proto = tcp-server
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243171   local = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243174   local_port = 465
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243177   remote = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243181   remote_port = 465
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243184   remote_float = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243187   bind_defined = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243190   bind_local = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243193   connect_retry_seconds = 5
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243197   connect_timeout = 10
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243200   connect_retry_max = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243213   tun_mtu = 1500
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243216   tun_mtu_defined = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243219   link_mtu = 1500
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243223   link_mtu_defined = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243226   tun_mtu_extra = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243229   tun_mtu_extra_defined = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243232   mtu_discover_type = -1
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243236   fragment = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243239   mssfix = 1450
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243242   explicit_exit_notification = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243245 Connection profiles END
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243249   remote_random = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243252   ipchange = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243255   dev = 'tun'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243258   dev_type = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243261   dev_node = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243265   lladdr = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243268   topology = 1
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243271   tun_ipv6 = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243274   ifconfig_local = '10.8.0.1'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243278   ifconfig_remote_netmask = '10.8.0.2'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243281   ifconfig_noexec = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243284   ifconfig_nowarn = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243287   ifconfig_ipv6_local = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243291   ifconfig_ipv6_netbits = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243294   ifconfig_ipv6_remote = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243297   shaper = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243300   mtu_test = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243303   mlock = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243307   keepalive_ping = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243310   keepalive_timeout = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243313   inactivity_timeout = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243316   ping_send_timeout = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243319   ping_rec_timeout = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243323   ping_rec_timeout_action = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243326   ping_timer_remote = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243329   remap_sigusr1 = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243332   persist_tun = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243336   persist_local_ip = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243339   persist_remote_ip = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243342   persist_key = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243345   passtos = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243350   resolve_retry_seconds = 1000000000
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243355   username = 'nobody'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243359   groupname = 'nobody'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243362   chroot_dir = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243365   cd_dir = '/etc/openvpn'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243369   writepid = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243372   up_script = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243376   down_script = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243379   down_pre = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243382   up_restart = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243385   up_delay = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243388   daemon = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243392   inetd = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243395   log = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243398   suppress_timestamps = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243401   nice = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243404   verbosity = 9
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243408   mute = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243411   gremlin = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243414   status_file = 'openvpn-status.log'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243417   status_file_version = 1
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243420   status_file_update_freq = 60
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243424   occ = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243427   rcvbuf = 65536
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243430   sndbuf = 65536
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243433   mark = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243436   sockflags = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243440   fast_io = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243443   lzo = 7
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243446   route_script = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243449   route_default_gateway = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243452   route_default_metric = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243456   route_noexec = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243459   route_delay = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243462   route_delay_window = 30
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243466   route_delay_defined = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243469   route_nopull = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243472   route_gateway_via_dhcp = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243475   max_routes = 100
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243479   allow_pull_fqdn = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243482   route 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0/nil/nil
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243486   management_addr = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243489   management_port = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243492   management_user_pass = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243495   management_log_history_cache = 250
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243499   management_echo_buffer_size = 100
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243502   management_write_peer_info_file = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243505   management_client_user = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243509   management_client_group = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243512   management_flags = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243515   shared_secret_file = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243519   key_direction = 1
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243522   ciphername_defined = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243525   ciphername = 'BF-CBC'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243528   authname_defined = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243532   authname = 'SHA1'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243535   prng_hash = 'SHA1'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243538   prng_nonce_secret_len = 16
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243541   keysize = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243545   engine = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243548   replay = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243551   mute_replay_warnings = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243554   replay_window = 64
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243557   replay_time = 15
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243561   packet_id_file = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243564   use_iv = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243567   test_crypto = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243570   tls_server = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243574   tls_client = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243577   key_method = 2
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243582   ca_file = '/etc/openvpn/ca.crt'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243585   ca_path = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243589   dh_file = '/etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243592   cert_file = '/etc/openvpn/Caluka.crt'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243595   priv_key_file = '/etc/openvpn/Caluka.key'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243599   pkcs12_file = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243602   cipher_list = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243605   tls_verify = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243608   tls_export_cert = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243611   verify_x509_type = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243615   verify_x509_name = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243618   crl_file = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243621   ns_cert_type = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243625   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243675   remote_cert_eku = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243678   ssl_flags = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243681   tls_timeout = 2
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243684   renegotiate_bytes = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243688   renegotiate_packets = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243691   renegotiate_seconds = 3600
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243694   handshake_window = 60
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243697   transition_window = 3600
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243700   single_session = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243704   push_peer_info = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243707   tls_exit = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243710   tls_auth_file = '/etc/openvpn/ta.key'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243714   server_network = 10.8.0.0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243718   server_netmask = 255.255.255.0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243724   server_network_ipv6 = ::
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243728   server_netbits_ipv6 = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243731   server_bridge_ip = 0.0.0.0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243735   server_bridge_netmask = 0.0.0.0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243739   server_bridge_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243742   server_bridge_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243745   push_entry = 'redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243749   push_entry = 'dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.254'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243752   push_entry = 'dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243755   push_entry = 'route 10.8.0.1'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243759   push_entry = 'topology net30'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243762   ifconfig_pool_defined = ENABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243766   ifconfig_pool_start = 10.8.0.4
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243769   ifconfig_pool_end = 10.8.0.251
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243773   ifconfig_pool_netmask = 0.0.0.0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243776   ifconfig_pool_persist_filename = 'ipp.txt'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243780   ifconfig_pool_persist_refresh_freq = 600
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243783   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_defined = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243787   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_base = ::
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243790   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_netbits = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243795   n_bcast_buf = 256
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243798   tcp_queue_limit = 64
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243801   real_hash_size = 256
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243805   virtual_hash_size = 256
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243808   client_connect_script = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243811   learn_address_script = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243814   client_disconnect_script = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243818   client_config_dir = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243821   ccd_exclusive = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243824   tmp_dir = '/tmp'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243827   push_ifconfig_defined = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243831   push_ifconfig_local = 0.0.0.0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243834   push_ifconfig_remote_netmask = 0.0.0.0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243838   push_ifconfig_ipv6_defined = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243841   push_ifconfig_ipv6_local = ::/0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243845   push_ifconfig_ipv6_remote = ::
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243848   enable_c2c = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243851   duplicate_cn = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243854   cf_max = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243857   cf_per = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243861   max_clients = 1024
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243864   max_routes_per_client = 256
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243867   auth_user_pass_verify_script = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243870   auth_user_pass_verify_script_via_file = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243874   port_share_host = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243877   port_share_port = 0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243880   client = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243883   pull = DISABLED
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243887   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243891 OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [eurephia] [MH] 
>   [IPv6] built on Nov 13 2013
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243915 WARNING: --keepalive option is missing from server config
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=243966 NOTE: your local LAN uses the extremely common subnet address 192.168.0.x or 
>   192.168.1.x.  Be aware that this might create routing conflicts if you connect to the VPN server from public locations 
>   such as internet cafes that use the same subnet.
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248226 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248427 PRNG init md=SHA1 size=36
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248465 Control Channel Authentication: using '/etc/openvpn/ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key 
>   file
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248473 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC 
>   authentication
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248479 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: HMAC KEY: e305511f 915b416f 2c39a855 a9442867 
>   f0845172
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248482 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: HMAC size=20 block_size=20
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248486 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC 
>   authentication
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248491 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: HMAC KEY: ca5a1d3b 0b06c73b d3019a91 5451b0cf 
>   c4e67eab
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248495 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: HMAC size=20 block_size=20
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248501 MTU DYNAMIC mtu=0, flags=1, 0 -> 168
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248505 TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1544 D:168 EF:68 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248509 MTU DYNAMIC mtu=1450, flags=2, 1544 -> 1450
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248518 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248570 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.1.254/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eno1 HWADDR=94:de:80:6f:2c:dc
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248679 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248691 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248701 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=248722 /usr/bin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=249340 /usr/bin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=249750 /usr/bin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250108 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1544 D:1450 EF:44 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250315 GID set to nobody
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250359 UID set to nobody
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250374 STREAM: RESET
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250380 STREAM: INIT maxlen=1544
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250388 Listening for incoming TCP connection on [undef]
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250402 TCPv4_SERVER link local (bound): [undef]
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250409 TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [undef]
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250418 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250461 IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62, ipv6=0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250474 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250483 EP_INIT maxevents=1028 flags=0x00000000
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250496 MULTI: TCP INIT maxclients=1024 maxevents=1028
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250519 Initialization Sequence Completed
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250526 SCHEDULE: schedule_find_least NULL
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250533 EP_CTL fd=5 rwflags=0x0001 ev=0x00000001 arg=0x00000001
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:33 2014 us=250543 EP_CTL fd=6 rwflags=0x0001 ev=0x00000001 arg=0x00000002
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:43 2014 us=260588 MULTI: REAP range 0 -> 16
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:43 2014 us=260648 MULTI TCP: multi_tcp_action a=TA_TIMEOUT p=0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:43 2014 us=260654 MULTI TCP: multi_tcp_dispatch a=TA_TIMEOUT mi=0x00000000
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:43 2014 us=260658 MULTI TCP: multi_tcp_post TA_TIMEOUT -> TA_UNDEF
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:43 2014 us=260662 SCHEDULE: schedule_find_least NULL
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:53 2014 us=270702 MULTI: REAP range 16 -> 32
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:53 2014 us=270721 MULTI TCP: multi_tcp_action a=TA_TIMEOUT p=0
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:53 2014 us=270726 MULTI TCP: multi_tcp_dispatch a=TA_TIMEOUT mi=0x00000000
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:53 2014 us=270730 MULTI TCP: multi_tcp_post TA_TIMEOUT -> TA_UNDEF
>
> Wed Jan 15 19:59:53 2014 us=270734 SCHEDULE: schedule_find_least NULL
>
> Wed Jan 15 20:00:03 2014 us=280776 MULTI: REAP range 32 -> 48
>
> Wed Jan 15 20:00:03 2014 us=280795 MULTI TCP: multi_tcp_action a=TA_TIMEOUT p=0
>
> Wed Jan 15 20:00:03 2014 us=280801 MULTI TCP: multi_tcp_dispatch a=TA_TIMEOUT mi=0x00000000
>
> Wed Jan 15 20:00:03 2014 us=280805 MULTI TCP: multi_tcp_post TA_TIMEOUT -> TA_UNDEF
>
> Wed Jan 15 20:00:03 2014 us=280809 SCHEDULE: schedule_find_least NULL

Sorry about the lenght of the post, tried to give as much information as I could.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're wrong and the port isn't opened.
Maybe your client is blocking the port.
Maybe something in your network is blocking weird ports.

Try using "443" port instead. It's usually left alone without blocking...